# Getting error messages in debmirror

Tags: debmirror

I upgraded my local mirror from Trusty to Xenial. Since then whenever it is updating I receive messages such as the following:

```
Use of uninitialized value $size in numeric eq (==) at /usr/bin/debmirror line 1645.
    Use of uninitialized value $size in numeric eq (==) at /usr/bin/debmirror line 1645.
    Use of uninitialized value $size in sprintf at /usr/bin/debmirror line 1679.
```

Packages still appear to be downloading but is there some issue here which needs fixed?

As requested by @N0rbert, here's the output of apt-cache policy debmirror:

```
debmirror:
  Installed: 1:2.25ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1:2.25ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 1:2.25ubuntu2 500
        500 http://192.168.166.191/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://192.168.166.191/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy debmirror` to the question.